# Why don't floated elements get overridden by a later defined style using a class targeting that particular element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-float

I am trying to analyze this code given as an example in w3schools.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the code that i am analyzing.

There are 3 things that i can't understand in this code.

1 - Why is the 'li.dropdown' made inline-block? What exactly is the purpose of making the list-item, which is floated, and therefore already inline-block, into an inline-block? I can't figure out what purpose does that serve.

2 - Why is it that when i make the "li.dropdown" into display block, it doesn't become block? The dropdown is floated, so when i make it block, shouldn't it override the float, and just span its width to 100%? Apparently it doesn't override the float, so why? And if it doesn't override the float, then why make it inline-block in the first place then?

3 - Why are "li a" and ".dropbtn" defined separately? The class .dropbtn is part of "li a", so why is there a need to separately define it using a class?

Comment: 1. removing that doesn’t appear to change anything, so it might simply be superfluous. (_We_ can’t always tell what an author’s intention might have been … especially not, when you source your examples from a site as crap as w3schools.) 2. Surprise, the _computed_ value was `block` before already - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo 3. Author’s choice? How should we know? There is always multiple ways to achieve the same end result.

Comment: I don't understand the answer to the 2nd question. The element is floated, but when i later make it display block, it remains floated. So, why did the float not get overridden? I get that the list-item itself is block, but it's floated, and the float doesn't get overridden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) inline-block and float together doesn't make sense - one of them is superfluous, (although they are not the same), preferably just use the inline-block display.

2.) Elements having `display: block` *can* be floated, and when they are, they don't automatically have 100% width, but are either as wide as defined *or* as wide as their content (very often an image).

The special thing about floats is that the content of their parent element can float *around*  them, or better said at one side  (depending if left or right), plus at its top and its bottom, depending, where it is positioned inside the HTML structure. The typical situation is again text floating around an image inside a div or a paragraph.

3.) `li a` applies to all `a` tags inside an `li` tag, in your code also to the links inside `.dropdown-content`, which are "grandparents of the `li` tag. So the class is their to only affect the `a` which has the class.

Comment: I think i already figured it out. It's the 2nd question that confused me the most, but i now figured out the second display block does not override the float because i am not redefining the float. I am only redefining the display, which is already block. w3school and their explanations and examples are really confusing and irritating to pedantic people like me. I spent all day trying to figure out the purpose of this simple code.

Answer (score 1):

1

```
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

is not necessary.

2
When an element is floated, it automatically becomes a block element, and a block formatting context will be generated to contains the element, floated elements have their own special display behavior besides block elements.

3
"li a" and ".dropbtn" defined separately?

It is redundant.

End

This article could help: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/